# How to get total number of commits using GitHub API

Tags: github, github-api

I am trying to collect some statistics about our project repositories on GitHub. I am able to get total number of commits for each contributor , but it is for default branch.

`curl https://api.github.com/repos/cms-sw/cmssw/stats/contributors`

The problem is , how can i get the same info for non-default branches , where i can specify a branch name. Is any such operation possible using GitHub API ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [GitHub's GraphQL API](https://developer.github.com/early-access/graphql/) to get at this data, although it won't be aggregated for you.

Try the following query in their [GraphQL Explorer](https://developer.github.com/early-access/graphql/explorer/):

```
query($owner:String!, $name:String!) {
  repository(owner:$owner,name:$name) {
    refs(first:30, refPrefix:"refs/heads/") {
      edges {
        cursor
        node {
          name
          target {
            ... on Commit {
              history(first:30) {
                edges {
                  cursor
                  node {
                    author {
                      email
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With these variables:

```
{
  "owner": "rails",
  "name": "rails"
}
```

That will list out each of the author emails for each of the commits of each of the branches in a given repository. It would be up to you to paginate over the data (adding something like `cursor: "b7aa251234357f7ddddccabcbce332af39dd95f6"` after the `first:30` arguments). You'd also have to aggregate the counts on your end.

Hope this helps.